# How do I remove this red error text produced by Pylint?

Tags: python, pylint

[image: Example]
I don't know why this is happening all of a sudden, before it only showed the red underline and I had to put my mouse over it to see the error message which is what I prefer. I tried my best to look this problem up but don't know how to describe this.

How to remove the text itself, and show only the highlight? Thanks in advance!

Solution: I was able to figure it out, it was an extension (one dark pro) I was using within VS code that creates the red error text. I thought it was a problem with pylint. Sorry about that and thanks for your guys help!

Comment: Fix the error in your code.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I just want it to show the red underline, not the red text because whenever I try to edit or add new code, the red text is attached to my cursor and it's annoying. But before it only showed the red underline, Idk what went wrong.

Comment: That's probably a GUI thing. What editor are you using?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi you're right lol, it was an extension I was using within VS code that does this

Answer (score 1):

The example you show contains a syntax error in both Python 2 and Python 3.  If something changed to cause this to be called out quite clearly, then that's a good thing, as this text won't run regardless of if your editor says that or not.

Why would you want to change the behavior in this case?  The answer here is clearly to add a `:` to your code.  If you get text you don't wish to have on your screen for problems that are not clear syntax errors, then I would suggest that you post an example of one of those...that is, post an example of something where it makes sense to soften the behavior of the syntax highlighter.

Again, to fix the problem with both the code and the highlighting, add a colon to the end of the first line, ie:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello")
```

As an aside...I would suggest that you use parentheses with all of your `print` statements even if you are currently using Python 2.X.  This will allow your `print` statements to work without modification if/when you switch to Python 3 (mentioned this only because difference between `print` in Python 2.X vs 3.X came up in the comments and other answer.)